# What is DirectX 11's equivalent of D3DCAPS9::MaxVertexIndex of DirectX 9

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-9

I'm porting a DirectX 9 program to DirectX 11. How do I get the value in DirectX 11 that is retrieved using

`D3DCAPS9::MaxVertexIndex`

in DirectX 9?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectX 11 uses "feature levels" to capture the bulk of device capabilities in set stair-step fashion. You should read about feature levels on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx) and in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) post.

Feature Level 9.1 supports 16-bit indices and Feature Level 9.2 or later supports 32-bit indices.

The MaxVertexIndex is essentially the same as "Max Primitive Count" on the MSDN Feature Level table.

- Feature Level 9.1 requires MaxVertexIndex >= 65534
- Feature Level 9.2 and 9.3 requires MaxVertexIndex >= 1048575
- Feature Level 10.0 or later defines the maximum vertex index as a
  full 32-bits (with the 0xFFFFFFFF value reserved for strip restarts)
  i.e. 4294967295

BTW, there are a few optional features that hardware can expose in addition to their defined feature levels, but there's really only a few dozen of these across the whole ecosystem. You use CheckFeatureSupport for most of these. You can use CheckFormatSupport for a lot of information, but the bulk of the settings here are strictly determined by the feature level anyhow. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219822.aspx) for the DXGI format support tables.